# Why is this widely used script killing my processor

Tags: javascript

I installed this popular, light-weight script on a website but it is running very poorly and maxing out my processor.

http://www.leigeber.com/2008/12/javascript-slideshow/

This is for sure my problem and nothing wrong with that script which runs fine for me on the demo site, but I have no errors and do not understand where the conflict lies.  Any ideas on how to root this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install firebug
2. Find an action (e.g. clicking on a picture) that causes slow down.
3. Using firebug put a break point next to where that action starts
4. examine the code

Comment: Thanks I am a big fan of firebug and I did not detect anything using it and it is a continuous problem, not necessarily tied to an action. Maybe i just need a new computer :P  Anyways good answer and really the only one for my ambiguous late night question.

Comment: Perhaps you can look through this 3rd party script for something that kicks off when you load the page and runs continuously, or fires frequently, in the background.